# VS Code / IDEs: How can I enable cmd+click goto definition for variables declared at runtime?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I'm looking to improve my own productivity by trying to figure out how to provide <kbd>cmd+click</kbd> functionality for variables declared at runtime. I work with a library that allows you to register objects to it at runtime to be accessed later — it would be great if I could cmd+click to definitions of these! How do you think I could achieve this? I'm open to any ideas. Thanks!

Edit:

Thoughts I have so far inspired by feedback from various Slack communities:

- There is no such thing as 'runtime' when providing functionality in IDEs
- We need to be able to teach the IDE about what definitions to expect. Whether this means writing an extension to use the VS Code API specifically for my use-case, or otherwise working within a system that generates files that the IDE already knows to look for, which allows it to connect the dots and provide the precious peek / goto definition functionality

Edit:

I'm starting work on a VS Code extension that reads a dotfile for configuration — I'll share what I find out as I go!

Comment: If they're declared at runtime, there is no definition available in the code editor, because they don't exist until the code is executed. Where would you expect that Cmd+Click to take you?

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah! This is definitely a barrier to providing the functionality — I've received similar feedback on this question and definitely agree — we need to teach the IDE how to find the definitions